# Reactor Kafka throws error ( Could not create new window due to lack of requests )

Tags: apache-kafka, project-reactor

We are using reactor kafka to consume messages from a kafka topic and we are also using reactor Flux's windowing feature to batch together records for certain duration as shown below.

```java
kafkaFlux =
    kafkaFlux
        .window(Duration.ofSeconds((Long) config.getAdditionalProps().get(WINDOWING_TIMESPAN)))
        .flatMap(....)
```

But Occasionally we receives below errors and our kafka consumer stop consuming messages after this error.

```java
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: reactor.core.Exceptions$OverflowException: Could not create new window due to lack of requests Caused by: reactor.core.Exceptions$OverflowException: Could not create new window due to lack of requests
at reactor.core.Exceptions.failWithOverflow(Exceptions.java:237)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxWindowBoundary$WindowBoundaryMain.drain(FluxWindowBoundary.java:346)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxWindowBoundary$WindowBoundaryMain.boundaryNext(FluxWindowBoundary.java:259)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxWindowBoundary$WindowBoundaryOther.onNext(FluxWindowBoundary.java:414)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxInterval$IntervalRunnable.run(FluxInterval.java:125)
at reactor.core.scheduler.PeriodicWorkerTask.call(PeriodicWorkerTask.java:59)
at reactor.core.scheduler.PeriodicWorkerTask.run(PeriodicWorkerTask.java:73)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Any help with the root cause of the error would very helpful. Thank You.

We expect to see our kafka consumer consuming messages without any error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue. Unfortunately, Reactor does not support backpressure in the `.bufferXXX` and `.windowXXX` operators:

https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/3416

https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/3106

You can try the workaround proposed here:

https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/3012#issuecomment-1153598695